# Jquery Ajax using json is getting a undefined value

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$.ajax({                
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: "checkit=" + $("#checkEmail").val(),
    success: function(response){
        $("#userCheck").html(response.status);
        if(response.status == true){
            alert("yay");
        }else{
            alert("dsfds");
        }
    }
}, 'json');
```

someone here suggested doing my ajax returns using json...

here is my php file returning the json..

```
$data = {success:true};
    echo json_encode($data);
```

im getting undefined for the return. Perhaps someone here could point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are also missing

```
dataType: 'json'
```

and your PHP is wrong:

```
$data=array('status'=>true);
```

**UPDATE**

Here are a few suggestions I would try:

1)  'dataType' (case-sensitive I believe)

2) try using the 'contentType' option as so:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

I'm not sure how much that will help as it's used in the request to your post url, not in the response.
See this article for more info: http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax
(It's written for asp.net, but may be applicable)

3) Triple check the output of your post url and run the output through a JSON validator just to be absolutely sure it's valid and can be parsed into a JSON object. http://www.jsonlint.com

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: for some reason adding dataType: "json", makes nothing happen.. none of my alerts will even work

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a different variable, you're sending `success` (invalidly at that) but checking `status`.  With your current jQuery, it should be:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
```

Comment: $("#userCheck").html(response.status);  is it the html part of this? it seems like it returns everything as html